# Avoiding create new ClickHandler Instances on every Click

Tags: java, gwt

im sitting on this for 4 hours now, and once again I end up on Stackoverflow because I just cant solve this (simple) problem.

I want to fire a method when I click a button, Google gives an Example like this:

```
// Listen for mouse events on the Add button.
addStockButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
  public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    addStock();
  }
});
```

But this creates a new Instance(?..How can they even create an instance of Clickhandler, since its an Interface) everytime the button is clicked. How can I solve this that all buttons share a Clickhandler and the Handler askes the Button which button he is, so he can fire the method attached to that button.

Any Ideas? If you this is to vage information and you require more code please let me know.

Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Answer (score 2):

Java creates a new instance of an anonymous class that implements ClickHandler. Which it can do because you provide an implementation for the onClick function specified by the interface.

This class is however not created when you click on the button but at the moment you call addClickhandler. If you need the handler for multiple events do something like:

```
ClickHandler handler = new ClickHandler() {
  public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    addStock();
  }
};
addStockButton.addClickHandler(handler);
someOtherButton.addClickHandler(handler);
```

Within the handler you can identify from where the event is coming using event.getSource().

If you have access to your button variables you could simply check the pointer

```
if (addStockButton == event.getSource()) ...
```

Or you can cast the result of getSource to the appropriate type and access the properties/methods of the object.

Comment: He also specified he wanted to do an action in the handler based on the type of button.

Comment: @Tnem: based onthe button to call action then use if (event.getSource() = "Add Stock")

Comment: @Tnem: added to my original answer. @Suresh S: Assuming you meant == instead of = how is comparing a widget to a string going to give a meaningful result?

Comment: this works perfectly, thanks a lot. And it is not inefficient? Would you  use this style of implementation of Handlers in a big project?

Comment: I don't think there is much difference in performance for both approaches. What to use depends much on the actual circumstances. But in general I think using seperate handlers (that then could call a shared method to avoid code duplication) would be better from a code quality point of view.

Answer (score 2):

Eelke has already answered your question. I just add that if you would use GWT's [UiBinder](http://code.google.com/intl/cs-CZ/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html) feature, you could achieve what you want like this:

```
@UiField
Button addStockButton;

@UiField
Button removeStockButton;

@UiHandler({ "addStockButton", "removeStockButton" })
void handleClickEvents(ClickEvent event)
{
    if (event.getSource() == addStockButton)
    {
        addStock();
    }
    else if (event.getSource() == removeStockButton)
    {
        removeStock();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its an anonymous instance of the interface, this is like declaring a new class that implements that interface.

I would have to ask why you would want to do this, you would need to make the `ClickHandler` contain a reference to its parent. You would also need to make the buttons identifiable so you can select the right one in the body of the `ClickHandler`. Is your need to only have a single instance really that bad that you can't have multiple anonymous instances ?

Comment: I read if I to do it like in my Post, it creates a lot of instances and consumes memory in the heap, and this is for university, so I dont want anyone to say its bad coding. Prof:"we always assume we live in the 1960s and every byte counts"

Comment: @Daniel Your Prof is wrong, every byte generally does not count. Premature optimization is pointless, you are better to profile the application then optimize if its needed. :D. Its better to create many instances that do one specific job than to create one instance that has a large `if else...` inside it. You suffer code readability for a marginal premature performance gain.

Comment: ok i see your point. My Knowledge is very shallow with those things, but its good to hear several point of views. thanks.